# Default definition in subclass of Eq in Haskell

Tags: haskell, subclass

I have a question similar to a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600470/how-to-define-default-implementation-in-subclass-definition-in-haskell), but where the superclass is `Eq`.  For example, suppose, I have the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class (Eq a) => Foo a where
  size :: a -> Int
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (==) s t = (size s) == (size t)
```

(Note, that I've included the language extension as suggested in the solution to the aforementioned question)

I receive the following ghci error message:

> ```
> Ambiguous occurrence ‘==’
> It could refer to either ‘Main.==’,
>                          defined at permutations.lhs:162:3
>                       or ‘Prelude.==’,
>                          imported from ‘Prelude’ at permutations.lhs:1:1
>                          (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Classes’)
> ```

Am I trying to do something impossible in Haskell?  I know that I could instead do something like

```
class (Eq a) => Foo a where
  size :: a -> Int

data Bar = Qux [Int]    

instance Foo Bar where
  size (Qux xs) = length xs

instance Eq Bar where
    (==) f g = (size f) == (size g)
```

but I'd then have to copy the definition of `(==)` for every instance of `Foo`, rather than making it a default definition.

I also realise that had I used by own superclass instead of `Eq`, I could have written

```
class Bam a where
  eqs :: a -> a -> Bool
  default eqs :: Roo a => a -> a -> Bool
  eqs f g = (size f) == (size g)

class (Bam a) => Roo a where
  size :: a -> Int
```

The issue I have is that the superclass is `Eq`, and that I don't want to repeat the same definition in each instance.

Comment: `(==)` is a method of the `Eq` typeclass. It cannot simultaneously be in scope as a method of the `Foo` typeclass. This is conceptually the same as having `foo = 1` and `foo = 2` in the same scope.

Comment: It seems like you just want `instance Foo a => Eq a where a == b = size a == size b`, but this is effectively useless because of problems with overlapping instances.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  It seems that I can do something like what I want for classes that I define (as I mention at the bottom of my question), but there are issues where the superclass is defined elsewhere.  Maybe I'm asking for something impossible.

Comment: The standard trick is to offer `eqDefault :: Foo a => a -> a -> Bool` and let people write `instance Eq Whatever where (==) = eqDefault`. I describe this in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34098924/791604). I'm tempted to mark this as a duplicate of that question -- any objections?

Comment: @DanielWagner: One. Add `fmapDefault` and `foldMapDefault` as `base` examples.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner for your suggestion.  I'd hoped to avoid having explicitly to make each instance of Foo also an instance of Eq, but I take it that this is unavoidable!  Please mark as duplicate if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define functions (and operators) with the same name, as long as they are in different modules.
So there is `Prelude.==` (default one), and yours (say, `My.==`). In the default definition of `My.==`,
compiler doesn't know which to use. Fix is trivial yet ugly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
module My where

class (Eq a) => Foo a where
  size :: a -> Int
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (==) s t = (size s) Prelude.== (size t)

instance Eq a => Foo [a] where
  size = length

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ a Prelude.== b
    print $ a My.== b
  where
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [3, 4, 5]
```

When run:

```
> main
False
True
```

Yet, i'd prefer to use some other operator name, for example `~=`.

Comment: You should probably mention that `DefaultSignatures` isn't necessary here, though it does no harm.

Comment: Thanks (and Merry Christmas)!  I really wanted to have the *same* `(==)` as in the Prelude, but I didn't make that clear in my question.  A previous commenter (DanielWagner) made a suggestion that works, but only by explicitly declaring each instance of `Foo` to be an instance of `Eq`.  I imagine that this is a barrier I cannot work around.